# How to find highly similar observations in another dataset using Spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two csv files. File 1:

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0
3,David,HM,Lee,M,,201211.0
6,66M,,Rock,F,,201211.0
0,David,H M,Lee,,1990,201211.0
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0
3,David,M,Lee,,1990,201211.0
5,Paul,ABC,Row,F,2008,201211.0
3,Paul,ACB,Row,,,201211.0
4,David,,Lee,,1990,201211.0
4,66,J,Rock,,1995,201211.0
```

File 2:

```
PID,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB
S2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,66MRockJF1995
S3,David,HM,Lee,M,1990,DavidLeeHMM1990
S0,Marc,HM,Robert,M,2000,MarcRobertHMM2000
S1,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,MarcRobertMSM2000
S6,Paul,Row,M,2008,PaulRowM2008
S7,Sam,O,Baby,F,2018,SamBabyOF2018
```

For example, I want to extract those highly similar observations in File 2 with **MarcHRobertM2000** in File 1. 
My expected output will be:

```
S0,Marc,HM,Robert,M,2000,MarcRobertHMM2000
S1,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,MarcRobertMSM2000
```

I used the following code:

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df2,'table')
query=""" SELECT PID, FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB, similarity(lower(FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB), 'MarcHRobertM2000') as sim
    FROM table
    WHERE sim>0.7 """
df=sqlContext.sql(query)
```

It looks like the `similarity` in SQL does not work in sqlcontext. I have no idea how to fix it. In addition, File 2 is big, around 5 GB so I did not use the `fuzzywuzzy` in python. And `soundex` is not satisfying. Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Levenshtein distance function to check the similarity.

Please refer to the below code

```
query=""" SELECT PID, FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB, levenshtein(FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB, 'MarcHRobertM2000') as sim
    FROM table
    WHERE sim < 4 """
```

Also please check https://medium.com/@mrpowers/fuzzy-matching-in-spark-with-soundex-and-levenshtein-distance-6749f5af8f28 for good read.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like we can only use either soundex or levenshtein. But levenshtein has a week point in identifying a string mixed with letters and numbers. For example, the distance btw str99 = '99 Broadway', str100 = '100 Broadway', and str999 = '999 Broadway', mentioned here [link](https://github.com/jiaqi216/pydata_dc/blob/master/fuzzy_search.ipynb)

Comment: @Samson I suggest you compare `Gender` and `dob` separately, and for Names+Addresses, use regexp_extract() to find the first number and save it as a column (i.e. street_number), then compare based on `sim < 4 AND other_conditions` where other conditions include gender, dob, street_number (based on how you want to handle null values, the condition can be a.dob <=> b.dob or any of dob is NULL etc).

Comment: @jxc Thank you always. I also though about separating `Gender` and `dob` information. In my data, there are many obs without null value in `Gender`. I tried to write a statement that the join guarantees either `Gender` is perfectly matched or one side has null value, `df7= df2.join(df5,(levenshtein(df2.FNAMELNAMEMNAME, df5.FNAMELNAMEMNAME) < 4)&(df2.GENDER==df5.GENDER | df2.GENDER=="" | df5==""))`. But it doesn't work. And does `a.dob <=> b.dob` mean `dob` can be either bigger or smaller? I googled but failed to find answers.

Comment: @Samson, `<=>` (used in SQL context) is same as `==` except that it returns true when both sides are NULL (similar to  df.column.eqNullSafe()) while `==` returns NULL and always fails. you can probably try add: `coalesce(df1.dob, df2.dob).eqNullSafe(coalesce(df2.dob, df1.dob))` to make a condition if `dob` are the same or one or both are missing(NULL). in Spark SQL context, for example use:  `df.where('coalesce(a.dob, b.dob) <=> coalesce(b.dob, a.dob)')`. or in a long format: `df.where('a.dob <=> b.dob OR a.dob is NULL OR b.dob is NULL')`