# How to apply spark.sql into worker nodes combining with df.createOrReplaceTempView()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I executed the following codes,

```
df6.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")
def func(partition_id, r):
    flmgd=str(r.FNAME)+str(r.LNAME)+str(r.MNAME)+str(r.GENDER)+str(r.DOB)
    query=""" 
    SELECT PID, FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB
    FROM table2
    WHERE FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB=\"%s\"
    """%flmgd
    df=spark.sql(query)
    list1=df.select('FNAMELNAMEMNAMEGENDERDOB').rdd.collect()
    if list1 ==[]:
        ID=None
    else:
        ID=df.select(['PID']).collect()
    yield Row(**r.asDict(),PIDF=ID)
df3=df2.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(func).toDF()
```

then I received the warning message

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

It looks like that the main issue is SparkContext is unable to be run in worker nodes. I googled but failed to find solutions. Would you mind helping me getting around this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What is is that you wanna do? This code is not going to work and the error says why

Comment: I understand the error meaning. I try to figure out a way how to pick up the most  similar obs in ``df6 ``for each obs in ``df2``. Recently, the above code is to choose the equivalent obs. But if it works, then I will think of a way finding the most similar obs not just the equivalent one.

Comment: Can't you do it without `mapPartitionsWithIndex`?

Comment: Do you mean using ``map``. If it is, then I think we are still going to face the same error. If there is any other way, would you minding providing more details. Thank you.

Comment: I also thought about using ``join(df6, levenshtein...)``. But the issue is that ``levenshtein`` has a weak point identifying the similarity in obs consisting of letters and numbers. You can check [link](https://github.com/jiaqi216/pydata_dc/blob/master/fuzzy_search.ipynb) for **str99 = '99 Broadway' str100 = '100 Broadway' str999 = '999 Broadway'**. And in addition, the file for ``df6`` is  large, around 5 GB.

Comment: You want fuzzy matching/similarity score right? Why don't you explain it in the question with some sample input and expected out and we can try to help you out?

Comment: You are right. Actually, I posted one related question before, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887715/how-to-find-highly-similar-observations-in-another-dataset-using-spark). You can find the input and expected out there.